# Track the historical change of Status

Tags: jira, tracking, status, expr

I defined the folloing Expr Formula:

```
history.changes.Filter($.field="status").changeGroup.map(CONCAT($.author.user_display_name(), " set on ", FORMAT_DATETIME($.timestamp, ""yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")))
```

to figure out who, when has changed the Status. Unfortunatly the last part of the concatinated string was not possible to display, the status itself.

`history.changes.Filter($.field="status")` will display only the different statuses in the history.

How can I incorporate this to to get something like this

"James set on 2023-05-15 07:05:12 to In Progress", "Maria set on 2023-05-23 08:02:55 to Resolved",.... etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out it by myself:

```
history.changes.Filter($.field="status").
changeGroup.MAP(
CONCAT($.author.user_display_name(),
" set on ",
FORMAT_DATETIME($.timestamp, "yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),
" to ", $.changes)
)
```